# UITextView Scrolling Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have an iOS 5.1 project in Xcode, and I have a view controller that, when you swipe left and right, changes the information on the screen **VIA UITextView**. I reuse the same view controller and the problem I am having is that when you scroll down and read the text and then swipe left, the scroll position doesn't reset to the top. Is there a function I can call that will reset scroll position?

ANSWER:

Found that this was what I was looking for:

[self.textView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,0,1,1) animated:NO];

Comment: no tableviews, just a simple textView w/ scrolling enabled

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
[self.textView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO];
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: should I place this is viewWillAppear? or somewhere else?

Comment: should work in view will appear--but it might be easier to create a new instance of your view controller for each screen, no?

Comment: (if you get low on memory any non visible view controllers should have their views automatically unloaded--you can reload them again)

Comment: also, if this is sort of multi-page scenario where there can be an unlimited number of view controllers, you could have just 2: create a new one for the page you are navigating to, and after navigation is complete, destroy the view controller that was just removed

Comment: this didn't work, I'm still getting the same position after each swipe

Comment: Found that this was what I was looking for:

[self.textView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,0,1,1) animated:NO];

Comment: [self.textView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO]; put it just before the self.textView.text= ot [self.textView setText:] hope fully it will work.. JohnnnBoyyy also provided the alternate way which will also work